# less css mixin with parametric A as default for parametric B

Tags: css, parameters, less, mixins

I'm currently working with LESS CSS and tried to create a mixin that mimics the default css behavior of shorthand parameters.

in css you often declare i.e.

```
margin: 5px 5px 10px;
```

and it's read as

```
margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
```

I tried the same with a border-radius mixin

```
.border-radius (@topright: 5px, @bottomright: @topright, @bottomleft: @topright, @topleft:  @bottomright) {}
```

I want it to take the first as default for all, if called with one parameter only. If I call it with 2 parameter it should take the first as default for the third and the second as default for the fourth.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior with LESS alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to receive just one parameter

```
.border-radius(@px) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @px;
    -moz-border-radius: @px;
    border-radius: @px;
}
```

Then you can call it with one parameter:

```
.border-radius(5px);
```

or with many. This requires you to either put them in a variable, or escape them:

```
@myradius: 5px 5px 10px;
.border-radius(@myradius);
```

or

```
.border-radius(~"5px 5px 10px");
```

I [read](http://www.markdotto.com/2012/04/05/comma-separated-values-in-less-mixins/) that the [Bootstrap project](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) uses the latter version for brevity.

Comment: I think I'll go with escaping them like Bootstrap does in the link, you provided. The article was a good read. Thanks a lot for link and answer!